# how to Device test Android 2.3.5 where is Developer option?

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, cocos2d-x

sorry, I'm little speak english..

How to device test Android 2.3.5???
Where is Developer option?
I do not know where the developer option button.

Answer (score 20):

Prior to HoneyComb, the developer options are found in:

<kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Applications</kbd> -> <kbd>Development</kbd>

Comment: Great.  But I cannot find "Do not keep activities" option there...  Please help @waqaslam

Comment: @CHAKRAVARTHI I believe that option together with some other advanced dev features were started to appear in API-11 (HoneyComb) and above.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean developer option and where do you refer ?

Please refer to this
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Answer (score 0):

Click on Window -> Avd Manager

There create a new AVD. Make it to Api 2.3.x - Then, when you start your app choose your simulator and it will start an emulator with the api level you defined before.

Note that in your android manifest file the min uses sdk version has to be the at least the android version  you want to test it fore

here's a link for the api versions if you scroll down a bit

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html